# OnTurnBasedMatchReceived Not Called

Tags: java, android, google-play-games

I'm working on my first Android app, it's a basic board game and I'm implementing Google Play Game Services with a turn based multiplayer game. I am able to start a match from one device, receive notification on another device (via the Play Games app/notification) and accept the invitation. I can play the first turn on the receiving device without any issues and it shows up on the device that the match was created from. However, when I take the next turn from the device the match was created on, it doesn't show up on the receiving device.

I've implemented an OnTurnBasedMatchUpdateRecevied listener (OnTurnBasedMatchReceived) and it gets called on the first device but not when an update is made on the second device. The listener gets registered in the onConnected method:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.registerMatchUpdateListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
}
```

and the listener:

```
@Override
public void onTurnBasedMatchReceived(TurnBasedMatch match) {
    byte[] data = match.getData();
    ...
}
```

Is there any way to check with the debugger or any other tool if the listener is properly registered? If I check the notifications in the Play Games app it will say that it is my turn so the OS is receiving them, but it's not coming through to my app.

Comment: Add a log tag at the top of onTurnBasedMatchReceived to see if it goes there, or if there is something in your code that is wrong

Comment: So I added logging and it doesn't appear in the log when it should have been called, so I assume this means it never got called.

Comment: Check the [Taking a turn](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/turnbasedMultiplayer#taking_a_turn) guide for GPGS multiplayer mode. To implement this you may need to attach a [OnTurnBasedMatchUpdateReceivedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/OnTurnBasedMatchUpdateReceivedListener.html) to your activity.

Comment: Thats what i have implemented, it works on the device that initiatws the match but not the receiving device. I am able to accept the invitation and make the second move of the match from the receiving device and it is received by the initiating device.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. Turns out it was because I was playing against myself on the same account, so the participantId I was passing to takeTurn() was my own.